# Why is this Django (1.6) annotate count so slow?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Summary: I'm getting very slow queries using few queries and annotate vs. two queries extra per item when counting related objects. Database is PostgreSQL 9.3.5.

---

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    have  = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='item_have', through='Have')
    want  = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='item_want', through='Want')
    added = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-last_bump']

class Have(models.Model):
    item       = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name='have_set')
    price      = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Want(models.Model):
    want       = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name='want_set')
    price      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And in my view, I list these Collections, and I want to show a count of how many wants and haves there are in each of them, doing that by doing an annotate:

```
class ListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Collection
    queryset = Collection.objects.select_related()
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(have_count=Count("have", distinct=True),
                                     want_count=Count("want", distinct=True))
```

This, however, makes my query very slow! I have about 650 records in the DB and django-debug-toolbar says it makes 2 queries and averaging around 400-500ms. I've tried with prefetch_related, but it doesn't make it any quicker.

I did try another thing, in the Collection model, I added this:

```
@property
def have_count(self):
    return self.have.count()

@property
def want_count(self):
    return self.want.count()
```

and removed the annotate from my view. With this instead, it makes a total of 42 queries to the database, but it's done in 20-25ms.

What am I doing wrong with my annotation here? Shouldn't it be faster to do the count in one query, vs doing many count queries?

Comment: One suggestion, when asking questions about debugging slow query, use the debug toolbar to get the sql queried being run and run EXPLAIN query for them. And post those sql query and the EXPLAIN in your question, that way will makes it easier for other people to answer.

Comment: "Shouldn't it be faster to do the count in one query, vs doing many count queries?" why would it be? SQL is a funny animal. I would suspect that you are generating huge cartesian products and then compressing them into counts in memory where as with `count()` you are just running super quick one off `select count(*) from table;` queries.

Comment: I think this is a combination of django annotate + postgres. I´ve got the same problem now and I´m "migrating" all annotations to .count(). It works much faster

Comment: If you are really asking "what is it that bogs down the query?" I would think that the distinct is slowing it down.  Granted you don't get what you want without it.  You could try to make it work with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

**Why it is slow**: If you simply used the **annotation by two ManyToMany fields** then you create an unwanted **big join of all these tables** together. The size of the Cartesian product of rows that must be evaluated is approximately `Have.objects.count() * Want.objects.count()`. You wrote then `distinct=True` to restrict finally the number of duplicated items to not get an invalid huge result.

Fix for old Django: If you would use only `queryset.annotate(have_count=Count("have"))` you will get the right result fast without `distinct=True` or the same result also fast with distinct. Then you can to combine results of two queries by Python in memory.

---

**Solution** A nice solution is possible in **Django >= 1.11** (two years after your question) by use a **query with** two **subqueries**, one for `Have` and one for `Want`, all by one request, but not to mix all tables together.

```py
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery

sq = Collection.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).order_by()
have_count_subq = sq.values('have').annotate(have_count=Count('have')).values('have_count')
want_count_subq = sq.values('want').annotate(want_count=Count('want')).values('want_count')
queryset = queryset.annotate(have_count=Subquery(have_count_subq),
                             want_count=Subquery(want_count_subq))
```

---

**Verify**: You can check both the slow and the fixed SQL query by printing `str(my_queryset.query)` that it is as described above.